# SharePoint 2010 : rebind each loop in listview

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, list-view, databind

Is there a way to rebind each loop in listview for a SharePoint web part ?
because I have a foreach loop, and my listview binds all the iterations but delete and show the last iteration

I have a foreach (string sdc in sdcNames)

{ var financialStatementDisplayData = linq query } ,

for each iteration I want to bind financialStatementDisplayData in a listview, the problem is that I find only the last loop binded .

for example if my loop have 4 iteration, my listview will have the last iteration variable, instead of the 4 iterations together.

this is my code :

```
  private void BindFields()
    {
        string camlString = string.Format(CAML_ASSESSMENT, AssessmentStatus.READYTOPROCESS, AssessmentStatus.WORKINPROGRESS);
        DataTable countriesDataTable = new DataTable();
        DataTable templateDataTable = new DataTable();
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

         try
        {

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                List<string> sdcNames = new List<string>();
                string rootSiteUrl = this.RootSiteUrl;

                using (SPSite rootSite = new SPSite(rootSiteUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb rootWeb = rootSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        sdcNames = SummaryReportUtilities.GetSDCList(rootWeb);
                    }
                }

            foreach (string sdc in sdcNames)
            {
                Uri siteUri = new Uri(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(rootSiteUrl, SITESURL + sdc));
                if (SPSite.Exists(siteUri))
                {
                    using (SPSite sdcSite = new SPSite(siteUri.AbsoluteUri))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb sdcWeb = sdcSite.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            SPQuery objQuery = new SPQuery();
                            objQuery.ViewFields = string.Format(DROPDOWNLIBRARY_FIELDS, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.AGENTID_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ID_FIELD,
                            SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.CREATED_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SALESFORCECASENUMBER_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD,
                            SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FILELEAFREF_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FILEREF_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ASSESST_STATUS_FIELD,
                            SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.PAXORCARGO_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD
                            );
                            objQuery.Query = camlString;

                            SPList dropDownList = sdcWeb.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(sdcWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, DocumentLibrary.DROPDOWN));
                            if (dropDownList != null)
                            {

                                // Retrieves Financial Statement
                                using ( DataTable financialStatementDataTable = dropDownList.GetItems(objQuery).GetDataTable())
                                {

                                    // Retrieves Country Lists
                                 //   string rootUrl = this.currentWeb.Url.Replace(this.currentWeb.ServerRelativeUrl, string.Empty);
                                    using (SPSite RootSite = new SPSite(rootSiteUrl))
                                    {
                                        using (SPWeb RootWeb = RootSite.OpenWeb())
                                        {
                                            objQuery = new SPQuery();
                                            objQuery.ViewFields = string.Format(QUERY_FIELDS, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.TITLE_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SDCNAME_FIELD);
                                            objQuery.Query = string.Empty;

                                            SPList countriesList = RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList(List.COUNTRIES);
                                            SPList templateList = RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList(List.FINANCIALASSESSMENT_TEMPLATECONFIG);

                                            if (countriesList != null)
                                            {
                                                countriesDataTable = countriesList.GetItems(objQuery).GetDataTable();
                                            }

                                            if (templateList != null)
                                            {
                                                objQuery = new SPQuery();
                                                objQuery.ViewFields = string.Format(QUERY_FIELDS, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.PAXORCARGO_FIELD, SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.TEMPLATELOCATION_FIELD);
                                                objQuery.Query = string.Empty;

                                                templateDataTable = templateList.GetItems(objQuery).GetDataTable();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                    // Joins Financial Statement and Country List using LINQ
                                    if (countriesDataTable != null && countriesDataTable.Rows.Count > 0 &&
                                        financialStatementDataTable != null && financialStatementDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                                    {

                                       var financialStatementDisplayData = from financialStatement in financialStatementDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                                                            from template in templateDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(templateItem => DataUtilities.GetSafeString(templateItem[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD])
                                                                                .Equals(DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD]),
                                                                                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && DataUtilities.GetSafeString(templateItem[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.PAXORCARGO_FIELD])
                                                                                .Equals(DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.PAXORCARGO_FIELD]),
                                                                                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                                            join countries in countriesDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                                                            on financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD] equals countries[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD]
                                                                            select
                                                                            new
                                                                            {
                                                                                AgentId = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.AGENTID_FIELD]),
                                                                                ItemID = financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ID_FIELD],
                                                                                SalesforceCaseNumber = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SALESFORCECASENUMBER_FIELD]),
                                                                                CountryCode = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.COUNTRY_CODE_FIELD]),
                                                                                FileLeafRef = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FILELEAFREF_FIELD]),
                                                                                FileRef = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.FILEREF_FIELD]),
                                                                                AssStatus = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ASSESST_STATUS_FIELD]),
                                                                                CountryName = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(countries[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.TITLE_FIELD]),
                                                                                SDCName = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(countries[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SDCNAME_FIELD]),
                                                                                ReviewType = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]),
                                                                                PaxOrCargo = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.PAXORCARGO_FIELD]),
                                                                                Created = DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.CREATED_FIELD]),
                                                                                SubmittedDate = DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),


                                                                                DaysDiff = Math.Ceiling((today.Subtract(DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD]))).TotalDays),
                                                                                DaysLeft =
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.NEW_APPLICATIONS, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? (4 - Math.Ceiling((today.Subtract(DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD]))).TotalDays)) :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.MAJOR_CHANGES, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? (4 - Math.Ceiling((today.Subtract(DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD]))).TotalDays)) :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.REINSTATEMENT, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? (4 - Math.Ceiling((today.Subtract(DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD]))).TotalDays)) :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.ADHOC, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? (4 - Math.Ceiling((today.Subtract(DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD]))).TotalDays)) :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.ANNUAL, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? (11 - Math.Ceiling((today.Subtract(DataUtilities.GetSafeDateTime(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.SUBMITTEDDATE_FIELD]))).TotalDays)) : 0
                                                                             ,
                                                                                EnableCreateButton = DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.ASSESST_STATUS_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentStatus.READYTOPROCESS, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? true : false,
                                                                                TemplateLocation = template != null ? DataUtilities.GetSafeString(template[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.TEMPLATELOCATION_FIELD]) : string.Empty,
                                                                                OrderIndex =
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.NEW_APPLICATIONS, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 1 :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.MAJOR_CHANGES, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 2 :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.REINSTATEMENT, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 3 :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.ADHOC, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 4 :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.ANNUAL, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 5 :
                                                                              DataUtilities.GetSafeString(financialStatement[SharePoint_Assessment_Fields.REVIEWTYPE_FIELD]).Equals(AssessmentReviewType.CANCEL, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? 6 : 7
                                                                            };

                                        financialStatementDisplayData = financialStatementDisplayData.OrderBy(category1 => category1.OrderIndex).ThenBy(category2 => category2.Created).ThenBy(category3 => category3.CountryCode).ThenBy(category4 => category4.SubmittedDate);


                                      //   Binds to Control                                               

                                        if (financialStatementDisplayData != null)
                                        {
                                            this.FinancialStatementListView.DataSource = financialStatementDisplayData;
                                            this.FinancialStatementListView.DataBind();
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        this.FinancialStatementListView.DataSource = financialStatementDataTable;
                                        this.FinancialStatementListView.DataBind();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } //end foreach


        }
              );


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LoggingUtilities.LogToDatabase(LOG_TYPE.ERROR, ex.Message, ex.ToString(), this.currentWeb.Url, this.currentWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (countriesDataTable != null)
        {
            countriesDataTable.Dispose();
        }

        if (templateDataTable != null)
        {
            templateDataTable.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi , Should you share your code to can help you faster ?

Comment: @M.Qassas I share my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's normal behavior to only bind the last iteration

because you set `financialStatementDisplayData` to your `this.FinancialStatementListView.DataSource` within `foreach` so it will set the last iteration.

To overcome this issue you should bind your query for each loop to **one main** `data table` then set this main `data table` to `this.FinancialStatementListView.DataSource` **outside** `foreach`

To set this query variable `financialStatementDisplayData` to data table do the following:

- Before foreach define a one main data table with the expected column as the following:

> ```
> DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
> dt.Columns.Add("first column name", typeof(int)); 
> dt.Columns.Add("Second column name", typeof(string));
> ... etc for all columns with its type
> ```

- Then at foreach after you get query variable `financialStatementDisplayData` do the following:

> ```
> foreach (var element in financialStatementDisplayData)
> {
>     var row = dt.NewRow();
>     row["first column name"] = element.Firstcolumnname;
>     row["Second column name"] = element.Secondcolumnname;
>     dt.Rows.Add(row);
> }
> ```

- After foreach completed set the data source for list view as the following

> ```
> this.FinancialStatementListView.DataSource = dt;
> this.FinancialStatementListView.DataBind();
> ```

Comment: you are the best. you help people without judgement. thank you a lot @M.Qassas